# differentiating between" more and more" and" further"

Tags: vocabulary

***UPDATED***:

Could you possibly show me in which circumstance you would distinguish between the following? when or where not?

> more and more
>
> further

Cheers,
nima

Comment: Not to mention it. You are wellcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like no **further** treatment.
>
> I do not wish to discuss this **further**.
>
> I would like to **further** address this after meeting.

You can use the word 'further' to express the word 'continuous', or 'continuously,' or to simply imply that the action will either continue or not continue.

'More and more' doesn't have to imply continuity. It usually isn't used in sentences because you could simply use 'more'. The only time I see it used is if someone is trying to emphasize how *much more* something is, and it is usually followed by 'until'.

> He began skipping class **more and more** [often], until he was finally expelled.
>
> She kept eating **more and more** food, until she felt like her stomach would burst.
>
> My child is growing **more and more** every day.